# How to make a form that updates a database?

Tags: php, sql, forms

I need to update a database (basically just perform some simple queries) when a user fills in some values in my form. I need the submit button to do multiple queries like:

```
UPDATE table SET column1 = column1 - $_POST['bananas'] WHERE id = $steamID
UPDATE table SET column1 = column1 + $_POST['bananas'] WHERE id = $_POST['steamid']
```

I am using this to post the information that will be used to update the database

```
<form action="bananas.php" method="POST">
Amount:<br>
<input type="text" name="bananas"><br>
Recipient SteamID:<br>
<input type="text" name="steamid"><br>
<input type="submit" name="bananas|steamid"><br>
<?php
if (isset($_POST['submit']))
  {
  // Execute this code if the submit button is pressed.
  $formvalue = $_POST['bananas'];
  $formvalue = $_POST['steamid'];
  }
  echo $_POST['bananas'];
  echo $_POST['steamid'];
?>
```

I can't have the queries active on the page giving errors because the values aren't filled in. They must only do the query and update my database when the user presses submit. How can I use this form to execute the queries I need when the user presses submit?

Things to note: `$steamID` is already the variable of the id of the user that is logged in, and I already have the connection to my database and all of that setup. The form is all I need help with.

Comment: OK, you have a form, and you know how to handle the form posting, and you have an UPDATE statement. Research MySQLi or PDO to see how to run a query. It's worth reading about parameterisation though - the `$_POST` in your SQL at present introduces a SQL injection vulnerability.

Comment: I know exactly how to run a query, I have a whole page of them on my site now. I just don't know how to run a query ONLY when a user presses submit.

Comment: (I think the reason for the downvotes, incidentally, is that you didn't make it clear you knew how to run a query, and appeared to be asking an overly broad question. Pleased you solve it, however!).

Answer (score 0):

Well, I just had somebody else figure it our for me, sorry for the trouble. 
I was stupid enough not to realize that you must put the query in `action="file.php"` and now that I know, the information is here for anyone else who has this question, and my problem is solved.